# determine the confidence level for the confidence interval $I_{\bar m}=(x_{(2)},x_{(9)})$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics, descriptive-statistics

> Let $x_1,...,x_{10}$ be a sample from a continuous random variable $X$
>   with the median $\bar m$. Determine the confidence level for the
>   interval $I_{\bar m}=(x_{(2)},x_{(9)})$. $x_{i}$ is the i:th smallest
>   value of the 10 observations.

**My attempt**

From the very beginning we let $x_{(1)}<...<x_{(10)}$ be the ordered sample, i.e the observations in "size order". Furthermore, we let $E(X)=\bar m$ and forms the confidence interval $I_{\bar m}=(x_{(2)},x_{(9)})$. But now, I do not know how to continue so that i can determine the confidence level for the interval. Should I suppose that the variable is from a distribution, e.g normal distribution?**Any hints or useful defintions/statements?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The interval runs from the second smallest observation to the second largest observation. The confidence level is the probability that this interval captures the median. To obtain this confidence level, first calculate the probability that the interval **fails** to capture the median. This event can occur in two ways: (a) the number of observations that lie *above* the median is zero or one, or (b) the number of observations that lie *below* the median is zero or one.

To calculate the prob of event (a), argue that the number of observations that lie above the median has a binomial distribution (with what parameters?), and argue similarly for (b).

Comment: in the book they say that we should use the properties of order-variable, but the book have never "talked" about it until now. Do you know these properties and perhaps a link? @grand_chat

Comment: Hint on the binomial parameters: There are ten observations, and each of them either lies above the median or lies below--what's the chance of lying above the median? (what's the definition of median?). Here's a link to what looks like a good reference: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/316

Comment: oh, so the probability is always $\frac{1}{2}$? but why is that? sorry if it's a dumb question. I think i make it more complicated for myself and "lose" myself @grand_chat

Comment: and thanks for link. It was indeed a good reference :) @grand_chat

Comment: The median of a distribution is the 'halfway' point of the distribution: half of all observations will be above the median (and half will be below). So if you sample $X$ from a continuous distribution, it will be above $\bar m$ with probability 1/2.

Comment: and above $\bar m$ with same probability right?  $P(X<\bar m)=P(X>\bar m)=0.5$ if $X$ is a continous random variable? @grand_chat

Comment: Correct. For a continuous RV the probability $P(X=\bar m)$ is zero.

Comment: exactly :) thanks a lot for the help! @grand_chat